# CSS nav menu background image

Tags: html, css, image, menu, background

I want to realize an horizontal menu with a responsive background image.

My problem is that if I put full-screen window the 'ul' menu is shifted respect to the background image. I even tried to set two different 'div' (one for the image and the other for the menu) inside a 'div' container but it doesn't work.

Moreover if I resize, the smallest window size, the menu comes out from the image bar.

I don't want to use 'px' settings, because I want to get a website that is as responsive as possible.

HTML and CSS:

```css
.menu {
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 11vh;
  background: url(../Images/menu.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 90% 10vh;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<body class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li> foo1 </li>
        <li> foo2 
            <ul>
              <li> sub </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> foo3 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your:

```
background: url(../Images/menu.png) no-repeat;
```

with:

```
background-image: url("../Images/menu.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Tip: Make sure the path to your img is correct.

I used the above and it works (with an img of mine of course).

Now for the responsive part, it is more common to add 3 images, 1 for each resolution you want and to set each image according to a @media query you will set.

For example:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .menu {
        background-image: url("../Images/menu1200.png");
    }
   }

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .menu {
        background-image: url("../Images/menu767.png");
    }
   }

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .menu {
        background-image: url("../Images/menu480.png");
    }
   }
```

Finally the best way to create a responsive menu is to use bootstrap. You should read more about it here [navigation bar](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp)

Comment: review the answer i did some edits. Also try to use the class menu into the container instead the div.

Comment: It doesn't work perfectly to me because my highest resolution width is over than 1200px but my image is at most 960px. I then modified your suggestion to adapt the padding-top and the font-size of the menu text instead and it works better. Unfortunatly this solution isn't that good for mobile view. I will continue to try on this way anyway. If I will obtain a final solution, I will let you know. Thanks for all.

Comment: Well you can always remember that the resolution width is up to you. Despite what most will say that the media queries have standard values, i suggest to you that you put the exact value that you want to change. Just inspect your page and modify your CSS there before you change it on custom file.

Answer (score 0):

In html standard a ul canot be a child of another ul,   you should  put your code like this to avoid html validition error

```
<ul>
     <li> foo1 </li>
     <li> foo2  
            <ul> 
                        <li> sub </li> 
            </ul>
     </li>
      <li> foo3 </li>
</ul>
```

a child ul should have a parent of a li
Then do the styling afterwards

Comment: Yes, sure. I make a mistake in copy-paste. My original code have this property.

Comment: it would be nice if you change the image to color in responsive view using @media